# Reject the claim that a sports league's regular season performance can occur by chance

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, combinatorics, conditional

For a tournament where each of $K$ teams plays each other team exactly once, what is the probability that the most number of games any team wins is $N$?  The answer to this question is to create threshold criteria to reject the null hypothesis that a the entire league's regular season performance can occur just by chance.

The conditional probabilities are difficult to deal with, because one team's win is another teams loss.  Each game is a 50% Bernouli trial.  The first team plays $K-1$ independent games.  The second team plays %K-2$ independent games, etc.  The last team plays no independent games because each win or loss for that final team is fixed by the random outcomes that were already counted for the previous games.

How to handle the conditional probabilities for those games that have already been determined?

The probability for the first team winning N games is binomial.  No need to deal with conditional probabilities for this team.

The probability for the second team winning $N$ games is binomial for the last $K-2$ games it plays.  The first game have already been determined in the game played against the first team.

The probability for the third team winning $N$ games is binomial for the last $K-3$ games it plays. The first two games  have already been determined in the games played against the first and second teams.

I am not sure how to create probability distributions for the games that have already been determined.  Considering the last team might be a good place to start when determining this distribution, because that teams win/loss record has been determined determined entirely by games the games it has played against the rest of the league.